# What are the ranking algorithms of name entitiy recognition, and which is best?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, analysis, semantic-web

For the NER (Name Entity Recognition) Tools, such as DBpedia, Zemanta, OpenCalais, Alchemy, etc., what are the algorithms they use and is there a preferred or common algorithm to use?

Answer (score 2):

Check [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) - a very nice and well-known algorithm for names matching (as they are heard in English).

Answer (score 2):

I last used the [Double Metaphone](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Metaphone), which uses heuristics to try and guess the original language to which the name belonged and thus the pronunciation it should lead to.

Ultimately though, such recognition does not work as good as one might expect. Most languages have rules for transliteration to Latin (also known as Romanization for Korean), so you might want to check about that first.